# Scala - convert ISO 8601 formated string with timezone to timestamp

Tags: scala, timezone, timestamp

String given : "2018-04-22T01:00:00-05:00"

Format required : timestamp

Code source :

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

val dateStr : String = "2018-04-22T01:00:00-05:00"

val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'")
val parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateStr)
val timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime)
```

But got error :

```
[error] (run-main-12) java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-04-22T01:00:00-05:00"
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-04-22T01:00:00-05:00"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Attention : There is a "-05:00" in the string which caused the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

`Z` is for timezones of format like `-0800`.

You need to have the timezone letter `X` in your pattern (and it shouldn't have quotes):

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssX"`

Also, `hh` is "Hour in am/pm (1-12)" I am guessing you want `HH` instead?

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"`

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX" works but : 2018-04-22T02:00:00-05:00 returns 2018-04-22 09:00:00.0, does 2 + 5 = 7 instead of 9 ??

Comment: It returns it in your local timezone, so for me I get `Sun Apr 22 08:00:00 BST 2018`